# How Can I forbid repeated characters using regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

How Can I forbid repeated characters using regular Expression?

This regular Expression should not allow

```
1--234567890
1--2345--1212
```

However following is valid

```
1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-0
1234567890
```

The only concern here is minus cannot be entered  after each other, so `--` should not match

There is no restriction in how many dash are in string.
I'm using C#

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead: `^((.)(?!\2))+$` will match a string with no repeated characters.

Alternatively -- potentially faster: do a search for `(.)\1` which will match a pair of repeated characters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. is it possible to apply this role to only minus characters?

Comment: Why not just check if the string contains "--"?

Answer (score 4):

This would match any pair of identical characters:

```
"(.)\1"
```

Alternatively, for word characters:

```
"(\w)\1"
```

So, if the regex matches, you want to fail validation.

---

Update:

Now that you clarified that only `--` is what you need to match on, here is another option:

```
"--"
```

Of course, you can simply use `Contains("--")` on the string in such a case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I only have numbers, parenthesis and +, - 
(barcode but something like phone numbers) so I guess should allow \d but not any duplicate of -

Comment: @BobSort - So what exactly _do_ you need? It is not clear to me.

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear enough. How can I change your rule to only apply to double minus character like '--'. I edited the question to explain what I like to do

Comment: That was exaclty what I was looking for. do you care to tell me how to make this condition negative in regex? I need to add it to a bigger regex, thanks.

Comment: @BobSort - Negating within a regex is much more complicated. To be honest, I don't know if this would be a good approach using a regex (especially if it is part of a bigger one), for efficiency reasons.

Answer (score 1):

If a dash is the only character you care about:

```
// this regular expression is "inexact", three dashes always has two dashes, etc
var bad = new Regex("--");
if (bad.IsMatch(input))
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Not a valid format", "input");
}
```

Or the far simpler:

```
// regular expression? no need
if (input.Contains("--"))
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Not a valid format", "input");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I need to add this role to a bigger regular expression so I cannot simply write part of it in c# [;)]

Comment: @BobSort: why does it *have* to be in the regex, is this regex being passed to something else?

Comment: I enter these regular expressions to an automatic barcode scanner that only accepts c# regex for validator (As of provider specification)

Answer (score 0):

This task is not suitable for regular expressions. What you probably want to do is write a loop that would go over the string and search for duplicates. The most efficient way of doing it is using some hash-based data structure like a dictionary.